# Sorcery manually encrypting password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I am trying to manually encrypt a password for comparison purposes.
I think that [this](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/model.rb#L117) is the method I need to call,
but `Sorcery::Model.encrypt('password')` does not work?

I keep getting `NoMethodError: undefined method encrypt for Sorcery::Model:Module`

Comment: I apologize because this doesn't answer your question, but why are you trying to encrypt passwords manually if you're using an Authentication framework? You shouldn't have to manage password encryption at all by using sorcery.

Comment: I am building an update your password function, where you need to enter your previous password (i.e. the original password) in addition to your new one, and I therefore need to hash the "original" password to compare it to the user's current password to see if they match before allowing them to reset their password

Comment: instead of `User.load_from_reset_password_token(token)`?

Comment: Yes, because that is if they forget their password, this is if they want to change it

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution for this.

Supposed Sorcery is under the default settings.

In the view: (I use slim for template)

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.label :old_password
  = f.password_field :old_password
  = label_tag :old_password
  = password_field_tag :old_password
  = f.label :password"
  = f.password_field :password
  = f.label :password_confirmation
  = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  = f.submit "Submit", class: "button"
```

Then in the controller, you could do this:

```
def update
  @user  = User.find(id) # find the user first.
  # this is the magic, use the saved crypted_password and salt to authenticate user's password
  authenticate = BCrypt::Password.new(@user.crypted_password) == params[:old_password] + @user.salt
  if authenticate && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    ... # updated and redirect or whatever.
  else
    ... # fail
  end
end
```

If you use other method to crypt password, you need change the magic line for proper method.

Maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to the previous question that its better to move validations to the model.
And a little gotcha is that when you initialize model with new `password` and `password_confirmation` attributes, it updates the current `crypted_password` and `salt` attributes in a `before_validation` filter, so the validation should be something like this, using dirty tracki:

```
unless BCrypt::Password.new(self.crypted_password_was) == (old_password + self.salt_was)
  errors.add(:old_password, 'is wrong')
end
```