# Rails: updates password without validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

For some reason in my app when a user updates password is skipping validations. Help me change that.

***Update method:***

```
def update
  if params[:user][:password]
    if current_user
      user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:user][:old_password])
      if user
        params[:user].delete :old_password
        if user.save
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been changed!"
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      else
        # old_password was incorrect
      end
    else
      # changing password while logged out
    end  
  end
end
```

***User model:***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
      attr_accessor :password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$/
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :password, presence: true, format:{  with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }, if: proc{ password_salt.blank? || password_hash.blank? } 
end
```

Comment: How do you know it's skipping validations? You haven't modified the record in any way, so it's presumably still valid. All you've done is loaded it, and then removed the `:old_password` key/value from `params`.

Comment: My form takes old_password, password and password_confirmation. I remove old_password and save the password and password_confirmation. I know it is messed up because i can save a password with two letters. Which doesn't follow my regular expression.

Comment: No, you don't. Nowhere in the code provided do you "save the password and password_confirmation". You *never* modify the `user` object. You just find it, and save it. You're not using `update_attributes` or manually assigning `password` and `password_confirmation`.

Comment: Your form takes `old_password`, `password`, and `password_confirmation`. You remove `old_password`, but, as meagar noted, at that point what happens and what you think happens diverge. You find a User object, you save that unchanged User object, and the unused `params` hash is garbage collected. Rails is not magic; all it does with a form is load it into the `params` hash. If you want to change the user's password, you have to *change the user's password*.

Comment: But @colinm tell me why my password is changed after that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a way to update user's password, this may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19697808/1758714

I use Sorcery for authentication, so maybe the code needs to change a little.